# Type conversion in C (demotion)

Tags: c, type-conversion

Can someone please explain this:

> When the destination is some form of unsigned integer and the assigned value is an integer, the extra bits that make the value too big are ignored.

I'm not getting what "destination type" and assigned value mean.

Above is a paragraph from C Primer Plus (6ed for me) Ch5 Type Conversions section at p.174

Comment: `unsigned int foo = signedIntegerThatIsTooBig;`

Comment: Does destination type mean the type used in the assignment statement? Or is it the conversion specifier in functions, say: printf()?

Comment: *destination* means the ending location - the variable being assigned to (the LHS); *assigned value* means the value being assigned to the destination variable (the RHS).

Comment: this is about type convertions

Comment: it means something like this int a; (unsigned char)a; -- this is legal

Comment: What does the **only authoritative** resource say? Where did you get this citation from? What makes you think it is correct? What does "too big" mean in this context? As cited, it lacks constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Destination" is referring to the variable being assigned to, i.e. the left side of an assignment, while "assigned value" means the value that is being assigned to the variable, i.e. the right side.

For example:

```
unsigned int destination = assigned_value;
```

As far as what happens when the assigned value is out of the range of the destination, section 6.3.1.3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding conversion of signed and unsigned integers states the following:

> *1* When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new
>   type, it is unchanged.
>
> *2* Otherwise, **if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value
>   that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the
>   range of the new type.**

This effectively means that the value is converted modulo the maximum value the destination can hold plus 1.  In other words, the extra bits are stripped off.

Comment: Answer says "what happens when the assigned value is out of the range of the destination, ...  when the destination is _signed_ ..." but fails to cite or explain that case.  "the extra bits are stripped off" is not specified behavior in C for _signed_ types.

Answer (score 0):

An exemple :

```
int          assign = -2;
unsigned int dest   = 2;

dest = assign ;
```

In the instruction `dest = assign`, `dest` is the destination of type `unsigned int` and `assign` the assigned value of type `int`.

Be careful doing this because `dest = 4294967294 = 0xFFFFFFFE` on a 32 bits architecture at the end of the program.

Answer (score 0):

I think the sentence shall be read like this:

```
 unsigned int destination = 258;
 \----------/               \-/
destination type          assigned value
```

In binary 258 is

```
1.0000.0010 (requires 9 bits)
```

but a unsigned char can (typically) only hold 8 bits so only the 8 right most bits are used and the remaining "extra" bits are ignored. Therefore the binary pattern for the unsigned char becomes:

```
0000.0010
```

which is the decimal value 2.